# Create rows based on columns value

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

```
+---+---+---+---+----+
| A | B | C | D | E  |
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | VK |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 9 | MD |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 9 | V  |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 | VK |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 9 | V  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | N  |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 9 | V  |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 7 | VK |
| 1 | 7 | 8 | 0 | MD |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | 9 | VK |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 8 | V  |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

I want to create rows based on columns value. For example, in the given dataset I want to select row based on  'E' column value 'VK' and two previous rows of Column 'C' to create a new row. A, B, D columns are irrelevant on the first datset.  Following this we should get a dataset like this:

```
    +---+---+---+----+
    | 7 | 6 | 3 | VK |
    | 1 | 7 | 5 | VK |
    | 7 | 8 | 5 | VK |
    +----------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic more clearly?  Why does row `D` disappear?

Comment: New rows only require values from column C and E. New rows should take one value from E column and 3 values from C column.  | 7 | 6 | 3 | VK |

Answer (score 0):

Defining the original dataframe, Using `.tolist()` to extract column C's values, then list slicing in reverse order to prepare the target rows, finally creating a new dataframe and inserting the target rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[1, 2, 3, 4, "VK"],
[1, 4, 6, 9, "MD"],
[2, 5, 7, 9, "V"],
[2, 3, 5, 8, "VK"],
[2, 3, 7, 9, "V"],
[1, 1, 1, 1, "N"],
[0, 1, 6, 9, "V"],
[1, 2, 5, 7, "VK"],
[1, 7, 8, 0, "MD"],
[1, 5, 7, 9, "VK"],
[0, 1, 6, 8, "V"]
], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
)

col_c_list = df['C'].tolist()
row_1 = col_c_list[2::-1] + [df["E"][0]]
row_2 = col_c_list[5:2:-1] + [df["E"][0]]
row_3 = col_c_list[9:6:-1] + [df["E"][0]]

df = pd.DataFrame([
    row_1,
    row_2,
    row_3
], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   A  B  C   D
0  7  6  3  VK
1  1  7  5  VK
2  7  8  5  VK
```

If the description was less ambiguous, I would recommend either `melt` or `stack` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Comment: Does this procedure automate the process? Seems like it is a manual solution. I have more than 1000 samples in the dataset and does require an automation process.

Comment: This might be helpful in answering @Gustav Rasmussen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125523/select-a-row-based-on-column-value-and-its-previous-2-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1